# Trying to create a dinner menu with a total of ingredients

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a random dinner menu for the week in Python. I would like to generate a random number of dinners and have the output list the dinners and the total combined amount of ingredients. Basically a list for the store. Examples would be pizza and spaghetti for two nights, and the total ingredients would be 2 cans of spaghetti sauce (1 for each dinner), dough, noodles, etc. I am very new to Python so I am only able to get to the random list without duplicating a dinner. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import random
print('Hello, this is what is for dinner this week ')
dinner = ['Beefy_Shells', 'Pizza_Bread', 'Spaghetti', 'Tacos', 'Chicken_Tostada']
# sample will make sure the same thing isn't chosen twice
x=random.sample(dinner, k=3)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. A few things you might not have seen in here, ask me any questions if they don't make sense.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

print('Hello, this is what is for dinner this week ')
dinner = ['Beefy_Shells', 'Pizza_Bread', 'Spaghetti', 'Tacos', 'Chicken_Tostada']

ingredients = {'Beefy_Shells':["Beef","Bread"],
               'Pizza_Bread':["Sauce","Bread"],
               'Spaghetti':["Sauce","Pasta"],
               'Tacos':["Bread","Beef"],
               'Chicken_Tostada':["Bread","Chicken"]}

# sample will make sure the same thing isn't chosen twice
meals = random.sample(dinner, k=3)
total_ingredients = Counter()
for meal in meals:
    total_ingredients += Counter(ingredients[meal])

for ingredient,count in total_ingredients.items():
    print(ingredient,count)
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know about the counter. It is almost exactly what I need. The total ingredients are listed but, the name of the actual random dinners are not. Is there a way to include this above the ingredients? Maybe, just add "print(meals)"?Thank you so much, Jimmy. This is awesome.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm going to be harsh motherhen and see if you can work out how to do this yourself. :-) Being good at coding/maths is just being confident in getting yourself stuck and then being able to dig yourself out of trouble. If you're totally stumped, let me know.

Comment: You're right, Jimmy. You have really helped me out. I'll work on it some more. Again, thank you so much.